# bison shift/reduce problem moving add op into a subexpr

Tags: yacc, bison, shift-reduce-conflict

Originally in the example there was this

```
expr:
        INTEGER
        | expr '+' expr           { $$ = $1 + $3; }
        | expr '-' expr           { $$ = $1 - $3; }
        ;
```

I wanted it to be 'more simple' so i wrote this (i realize it would do '+' for both add and subtract. But this is an example)

```
expr:
        INTEGER
        | expr addOp expr           { $$ = $1 + $3; }
        ;

addOp:
          '+' { $$ = $1; }
        | '-' { $$ = $1; }
        ;
```

Now i get a shift/reduce error. It should be exactly the same -_- (to me). What do i need to do to fix this?

edit: To make things clear. The first has NO warning/error. I use %left to set the precedence (and i will use %right for = and those other right ops). However it seems to not apply when going into sub expressions.

Comment: Shift/reduce conflicts are normal, but a rule that is both left and right recursive doesn't match the yacc parser design well and is unnecessarily complex. If you make it left recursive it will work better and have no conflicts. See `q4.y` below.

Comment: As a side note, your second version doesn't do what you think it does. It will return "4" for "2 - 2".

Comment: Also, the `{ $$ = $1; }` rule is implicit - you only need to write out the rules if it's something other than that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the conflicts involve just those two rules? The first one should have more conflicts than the second. At least with one symbol of look-ahead the decision to shift to a state with addOp on the stack is easier the second time around.

*Update* (I believe I can prove my theory... :-):

```
$ cat q2.y
%% expr: '1' | expr '+' expr | expr '-' expr;
$ cat q3.y
%%  expr: '1' | expr addOp expr;
    addOp: '+' | '-';
$ yacc q2.y
conflicts: 4 shift/reduce
$ yacc q3.y
conflicts: 2 shift/reduce
```

---

Having said all that, it's normal for yacc grammars to have ambiguities, and any real-life system is likely to have not just a few but literally *dozens* of shift/reduce conflicts. By definition, this conflict occurs when there is a perfectly valid shift available, so if you don't mind the parser taking that shift, then don't worry about it.

Now, in `yacc` you should prefer left-recursive rules. You can achieve that *and* get rid of your grammar ambiguity with:

```
$ cat q4.y
%% expr: expr addOp '1' | '1';
  addOp: '+' | '-';
$ yacc q4.y
$
```

Note: no conflicts in the example above. If you like your grammar the way it is, just do:

```
 %expect 2
%%  expr: '1' | expr addOp expr;
    addOp: '+' | '-';
```

Comment: i used %left '-' '+' to make the first not have a shift/reduce rule. The second it doesnt seem to apply, which kind of sucks and i have no idea how to make it apply (%left addOp doesnt work since it isnt a token)

Comment: I guess I would recommend that you modify your grammar so it's essentially my `q4.y`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the rule

```
expr: expr addOp expr { ..action.. }
```

has no precedence.  Normally rules get the precedence of the first token on the RHS, but this rule has no tokens on its RHS.  You need to add a %prec directive to it:

```
expr: expr addOp expr %prec '+' { ..action.. }
```

to explicitly give the rule a precedence.

Note that doing this doesn't get rid of the shift/reduce conflict, which was present in your original grammar.  It just resolves it according to the precedence rules you specify, which means that bison won't give you a message about it.  In general, using precedence to resolve conflicts can be tricky, since it can hide conflicts that you might have wanted to resolve differently, or might be unresolvable in your grammar as written.

Also see my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410875/yacc-bison-minimize-amount-by-grouping-math-ops) question

Comment: I would go so far as to group `+` and `-` under the same token in the lexer, but that might not be preferable to some. It works either way.